# Javascript and jquery in same page conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict

I am using javascript and Jquery in same page.

Some thing is preventing JQuery from working properly
I tried using `$jq = jQuery.noConflict();` it is not solving.

My code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dropmenu.js"></script> 
<script src="js/beaverslider.js"></script>                                                
<script src="js/beaverslider-effects.js"></script>   

<script>
$jq = jQuery.noConflict();
$jq(document).ready(function($){
    $("#nav-one").dropmenu();
});
</script>


<script>

    $(function(){
      var slider = new BeaverSlider({
        structure: {
          container: {
            id: "my-slider",
            width: 1000,
            height: 200
          }
        },
        content: {
          images: [
            "images/banner01.png",
            "images/banner02.png"
          ]
        },
        animation: {
          effects: effectSets["fadeSet"],
          interval: 4000
        }
      });   
    });

    </script>
```

Problem

javascript code was image fade effect and jquery code was menu dropdown effect.
when menudrop down appears, i was not able to click the dropdown menu link and when image fades dropdown menu also fades.

Please help me to find soln.

Comment: Just a point of clarification, jQuery _is_ JavaScript. JavaScript is the language, jQuery is a toolset written in that language.

Comment: Yes correct,In order to be more specific what i am doing i seperated them while explaining my problem.

Comment: Can be a plugin collision, or because you are not executing second script in dom ready, can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: Actually `$(function(){ ... });` is shorthand for `$(document).ready` (http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: why are you using .noConflict()? the only time you would need to use that is if you are using some other library which also uses the `$` sign (which in your case, none of the others do).

I thing your issue is more based on your implementation, not actually an issue with jQuery

Answer (score 2):

After calling `$jq = jQuery.noConflict();` `$` is [no longer a reference to jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).
In second script use either `$jq` or `jQuery` instead of `$`.